# How to set up Spark to use pandas managed by anaconda?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

We've updated the Spark version from 2.2 to 2.3, but admins didn't update the pandas. So our jobs fail with the following error:

> ImportError: Pandas >= 0.19.2 must be installed; however, your version was 0.18.1

Our admin team suggested to created a VM downloading latest version from anaconda (using the command `conda create -n myenv anaconda`).

I did that and after activating the local environment using `source activate myenv` when I logged into pyspark2 then I found it was picking the new version of pandas.

But when I am submitting a job using `spark2-submit` command then it is not working. I did added the below configuration in the `spark2-submit` command

```
--conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled=true  
--conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type=conda 
--conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.requirements=/home/<user>/.conda/requirements_conda.txt --conf spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path=/home/<user>/.conda/envs/myenv/bin
```

Also I did zipped whole python 2.7 folder and passed that in the `--py-files` option along with other .py files `--py-files /home/<user>/python.zip`, but still getting the same version issue for pandas.

I tried to follow the instruction specified in the URL https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/104947/using-virtualenv-with-pyspark.html , but still no luck yet.

How to fix it and be able to `spark2-submit` with the proper pandas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to define environment variables such as `SPARK_HOME` and `PYTHONPAH` pointing to corresponding locations in your virtualenv.

```
export SPARK_HOME=path_to_spark_in_virtualenv
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python
```